# Телеграм-Бот циклически берет сообщения

Tags: java, telegram

Использую данное `API`: [https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api](http://pengrad) для работы с `Telegram Bot` . Создал бота, установил ему `/setinline` и  `/setinlinegeo`. Когда пользователь пишет в любом чате ИмяБота то все хорошо работает, но если юзер пишет боту в приват, то бот начинает циклически выбирать все сообщания. Вот код:

```
int lastUpdateId = 0;
    while (true) {
        GetUpdatesResponse updatesResponse = bot.execute(new GetUpdates().limit(lastUpdateId).offset(1).timeout(0));
        System.out.println(lastUpdateId);
        List<Update> updates = updatesResponse.updates();
        if (updates.size() > 0) {
            lastUpdateId++;
            for (Update update : updates) {
                try {
                    lastUpdateId = update.updateId();
                    Message message = update.message();
                    InlineQuery inlineQuery = update.inlineQuery();
                    if (inlineQuery != null) {
                        Location location = inlineQuery.location();
                        String id = update.inlineQuery().id();
                        InlineQueryResultLocation r1 = new InlineQueryResultLocation(id, location.latitude(), location.longitude(), "Ваша локация");
                        //  bot.execute(new AnswerInlineQuery(update.inlineQuery().id(), r1));
                    }
                    if (message != null && message.chat() != null) {
                        Long id = message.chat().id();
                        System.out.println(message);
                        //  bot.execute(new SendMessage(id,"текст"));

                    }
                    System.out.println(lastUpdateId); // показать что выбирает в цикле
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Максимальный апдейт_ид = 898228320 , но постоянно в цыкле выбирает (898228315,898228318,898228319,898228320) и опять по новой... Т.е. метод `new GetUpdates().limit(lastUpdateId).offset(1).timeout(0)` должен вернуть 1 сообщение которое больше чем lastUpdateId, но возвращает почему то 4 сообщения даже если изначально ограничить `int lastUpdateId = 898228321;`...(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: взял другое АПИ.